Puppet Environments, Classes, and Config groups grayed out after foreman upgrade
I am trying to bring our foreman environment up to the latest version. I upgraded foreman from 2.3.5 -> 2.4.1 -> 2.5.4 -> 3.0.1 -> 3.1.3
The 2.5.4 version displayed the following messages:

Puppet Environments management is being extracted to the foreman_puppet plugin and will be removed from core in 3.0
Puppet Classes management is being extracted to the foreman_puppet plugin and will be removed from core in 3.0
Config Groups are being extracted to the foreman_puppet plugin and will be removed from core in 3.0
Smart Class Parameters management is being extracted to the foreman_puppet plugin and will be removed from core in 3.0

Classes were grayed out after 3.0.1 upgrade.
I reviewed the documentation and notice the following step,  I had previously run foreman-installer without any options.
sudo foreman-installer --foreman-proxy-puppet true --foreman-proxy-puppetca true --foreman-proxy-content-puppet true --enable-puppet --puppet-server true --puppet-server-foreman-url "https://foreman-clone2.mydomain.com"

So I upgraded to 3.1.3 and ran the command which failed due to --foreman-proxy-content-puppet true flag being invalid.  So I reran without the flag.
sudo foreman-installer --foreman-proxy-puppet true --foreman-proxy-puppetca true --enable-puppet --puppet-server true --puppet-server-foreman-url "https://foreman-clone2.mydomain.com"

Importing Environment did not fix issue.
I am not sure what I missed here.   I assume the issue is with moving puppet from core to plugin but don't know how to correct.
Versions

(PostgreSQL) 12.20
puppet --version
6.28.0
Oracle Linux Server release 8.10

We are not running katello.
I followed steps here
https://docs.theforeman.org/3.1/Upgrading_and_Updating/index-katello.html
using el8 repos instead of el7 and skipping Katello and centos-release-scl-rh updates.
Excerpt of /var/log/foreman/production.log
2024-09-19T08:00:05 [W|app|] Creating scope :completer_scope. Overwriting existing method Organization.completer_scope.
2024-09-19T08:21:18 [I|app|3d5aa4c4] Started GET "/repos/epel/repodata/repomd.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-09-19 08:21:18 -0400
2024-09-19T08:21:18 [F|app|3d5aa4c4]
 3d5aa4c4 | ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/repos/epel/repodata/repomd.xml"):
 3d5aa4c4 |
 3d5aa4c4 | lib/foreman/middleware/logging_context_request.rb:11:in `call'
2024-09-19T08:22:48 [I|app|fd0f6ecc] Started POST "/api/hosts/facts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-09-19 08:22:48 -0400
2024-09-19T08:22:49 [I|app|fd0f6ecc] Processing by Api::V2::HostsController#facts as JSON```


Have you looked at the logs? Do you have a test environment where you tried this first?

@NasirRiley  This is a clone of our production server.
I added a snippet of the production.log above.  It looks like ruby does not have the full path to the epel repo.  I don't really know ruby so I might be misreading this.
Nothing else gets logged at error level.

To begin with, you are running a very old release of Puppet which has likely lost its compatibility. Puppet is currently at 7.33.0 and you are an entire major release behind and then some. Foreman is currently at 3.11 and you have gone from 2.3.5 to several releases ahead where there have been major changes which along with the same being true for Puppet, are most likely causing what you are seeing. As this is a clone, the first thing that you can try is to update Puppet to at least 7 and see if that does anything.

An even better method is to do a fresh install of Foreman and Puppet on another system with more recent releases and then migrate the hosts over to the new one. That is what I do instead of in-place upgrades unless there is a security vulnerability that requires such an upgrade.
